# Default ribbon tab in Sitecore content editor changed after adding a button

Tags: sitecore, content-editor

I have created a new button in the Sitecore content editor ribbon. When I open the content editor in Sitecore the newly created button tab opens by default but I want the home tab to be opened by default as it was before adding a new tab
[screenshot of created button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xb6ha.png)

I have created new buttons also but the same issue occured
Is there any way to fix this

Comment: You sure this happens when you open Content Editor and not when selecting an item in the tree?

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore remembers which tab you had open last while navigating between tabs
regardless of the order of your tabs in the ribbon. So, if you are viewing your newly created "Custom Tab" tab on one item and then select another item, it should keep the "Custom Tab" open on the new item too and not to switch to the "Home" one.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. OP said "When I open the content editor..." and (for me) opening the content editor opens the default tab, but I can't find what determines the default tab (sets the scRibbonNavigatorButtonsActive class) .

Comment: After a test (putting 'home' second), it seems Sitecore will open the first tab, so I don't know how OP is having a different experience. Maybe you're right and I don't understand the question.